# Can't update values in Service, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS, and I have some trouble to update values in Service, Here is my code:

JS

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    function TestController($scope,$element){
    }
    function InfoController($scope,$element,$http,testService){
        $scope.$watch(function () { return testService.getHandler(); },
            function (value) {
                $scope.sel = value;
                var sel = $scope.sel;
                $http.get('hanlder',{params: {sel:sel}}).success(function(resp) {
                    $scope.data = resp['data'];
                });
            }
        );
    }
    function OptionController($scope,$element,$http,testService){
        var list = $element;
        list.on('click',".list-group-item",function() {
            var sel = $(this).text();
            testService.setHandler(sel);
        });
    }
    function testService() {
        var property = "List";
        return {
            setHandler: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);  //After click, property == msg
                property = msg;
            },
            getHandler: function () {
                console.log(property); //But property in getHandler doesn't change // != msg
                return property;
            }
        };
    }
    angular.module('testModule', [])
        .service('testService', testService)
        .controller('TestController', TestController)
        .controller('InfoController', InfoController)
        .controller('OptionController', OptionController);
})();
```

After click ".list-group-item" in OptionController, new value `sel` will be send to `testService.setHandler` (==msg), and change value `property` in testService, so getHanler will return new value and InfoController will have new value `sel`.

But, in real app, `property` in `getHanlder` doesn't change, and InfoController can't get new value `sel` to run `$http.get()`. Please, help me to fix that:)

Here my html:

```
<section ng-app = "testModule" ng-cotroller="TestController" class="main-content">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 list-group" ng-controller="InfoController">
      <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ng-show="sel">{{sel}}
      </div>

      <!--Before click-->
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-if="sel == 'List'">Choose one in right!</div>

      <!--After click-->
      <div class="list-group-item sel-dat" ng-repeat="dat in data track by $index" ng-if="sel != 'List'">
        <h4>Name: {{dat.name}}</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 list-group aa" ng-controller="OptionController">
      <div class="list-group-item">Users</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">Kinds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your exact problem at first glance, but it isn't anything wrong with your service. The first thing you should do is remove the use `$element` from your controllers, as that is not the way you should be writing angular.

I have written a small fiddle that achieves your desired service functionality. There are two main differences to your code.

The first is wrapping your service data in a state. This allows for easier binding and manipulating outside of your service, as well as protecting your actual service state root object.

The second is by removing any use of `$element`, and utilising `ng-click` to manage your click response inside your controllers. A general rule of angular is to not access the DOM inside a controller.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fjnuemj6/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 list-group" ng-controller="MainController">

    <div class="selected">{{state.prop || 'Not Selected'}}</div>

    <div class="option-list">
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeType('Users')">Users</div>
      <div class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeType('Kinds')">Kinds</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', function($scope, testService){
    $scope.state = testService.getState();

    $scope.changeType = function(type){
        testService.setProp(type);   
    }
})

.service('testService', function(){
    var state = {};

    return {
        getState: function(){ return state; },
        setProp: function(prop){ state.prop = prop; }
    };
});
```

Comment: It work when I change `.click` funtion to `ng-click`. Your answer relly helpful!! Thank you so much :)